# Pointwise convergence of the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=nx^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that $f_n(x)=nx^n$ converges pointwise on $[0,1]$?

Comment: With difficulty, since it doesn't.

Comment: @Mathgirl: Maybe you mean on $[0,1)$?

Comment: @par I've already removed my comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't converge for $x = 1$. So you have to only consider $x \in [0,1)$.

Then, you are considering $\lim_{n \to \infty} n  x^n$. I suggest using L'hopital's rule, first writing it as:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{(1/x)^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{e^{-n \log x}}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Assume first that $x \in (0,1)$. One has $\log x<0$ and
$$
\log \left(f_n(x)\right)=\log n+ n \log x= n \log x \cdot\left(1+\frac{\log n}{n\log x}\right) \to-\infty
$$ this implies by continuity that, for any $x \in (0,1)$,
$$
f_n(x) \to 0, 
$$ then one sees it remains true for $x=0$.

Comment: for $x \in [0,1)$ and $x \neq 0$ we can say that $|x|=\dfrac{1}{1+|c|}$ for $|c|>1$. so there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k \leq 1+|c|$ so $|x|≤ \dfrac {1}{k}$ and $\dfrac{n}{k^n}$ converges to $0$ so $n|x|^n$ converges to $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in [0,1)$ pointwise. Can it be done like this also?